# Laraver: I'm always getting this error when I call a controller in another controller: "Class 'CoreController' not found"

Tags: php, laravel, controller

When I'm calling a controller in another controller in laravel 5.8 I'm always getting this error: "Class 'CoreController' not found" even though I called the use method "use CoreController;".

I checked many times for spelling errors and I even restarted apache to see if is a problem with my server but still no results.

An image about the problem to be more clear:
[image: the problem]

```php
// This is the controller where I'm calling the "CoreController" I know kinda confusing names :P

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use CoreController;

// The class
class PageController extends Controller

// the function
public function dashboard()
{
  $core = new CoreController;

  return view('pages.dashboard')->with('core', $core);
}
```

Comment: where do you require the CoreController class file?

Comment: Basically in all my controllers because it will provide basic functionalities.

Comment: And where is that CoreController?

Comment: update `new CoreController` with `new CoreController()`

Comment: @Amarnasan "app/Http/Controllers/CoreController.php" the directory for it but basically in the default folder for controllers.

Comment: @Gulshan still the same problem.

Comment: And you sure named a class in that file called CoreController, right? :-)

Comment: @Amarnasan `namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CoreController extends Controller`

Comment: @Amarnasan so I'm pretty sure that there is a class called "CoreController"

Comment: Actually I think you don't need that "use CoreController" at all.

Comment: @Amarnasan "My code doesn't work but why, my code works but WHY ?" :D (It works now btw)

Comment: @Gulshan it doesn't matter if class you want to instantiate doesn't have constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say

```
use XXXXXXController;
```

is a way of saying "From now on, every reference to XXXXXController must be found in \XXXXXController.

So, by including that line, you got exactly the opposite of what you wanted, because that CoreController class was already well mapped, until you included that line and said "Ok, forget the original mapping of CoreController, now go search CoreController to "\". Where, obviously, it was not.